# Is it possible to send packets to an exe file? Or to control one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, enet

I want to somehow control a game in the background. In order to do so I either need to send packets to it, ENeT packets. Or to control it but in the background, because having it as the focused window is annoying. I don't know where to start from nor what to do, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: "Is it possible?" Sure, it's possible. But a Stack Overflow question needs to be _narrow and specific_ to be on-topic. You haven't specified _any_ environment details here, and if you mean to simulate a network environment, the environment matters massively -- you'll get different answers on Linux (where private network namespaces, tun/tap devices, etc. are options); different answers when you can encapsulate your application in a VM (and how feasible this is depends very much on the individual application, its performance and hardware requirements, etc) and much else.

Comment: What do you even _mean_ by "send packets to an exe"? If you just mean send UDP packets using the normal network stack, it doesn't matter _what_ kind of application is on the other end; you send UDP packets to an exe the same way you send them to a Java program, another Python script, etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.